# How to know locked file process VB6

Tags: vba, windows, process, vb6

Facing one sporadic issue in legacy application developed in VB6. Application produces intermediate file and then tries to delete it once required output is produced. Application does delete files properly but sometimes, I am getting error stating "Path/File access error". I have tried adding delay to delete but this issue is not getting resolved.
I wanted to search if there is any possibility to check process name which has acquired lock in VB6. I tried searching but no luck so far.
Could anyone please tell me any way I can get process name which has locked file and causing to not delete?

Please note that this issue happens infrequently.

Comment: You should probably have created the files with the [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) flag. If nothing else, you wouldn't be chasing this issue now.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Actually, file creation is not in our code. Excel is creating .ps file and MakePDF.exe is creating PDF from .ps file. Once PDF is created, we have logic to delete intermediate files. Here intermediate file is .ps. Our code do not have control over how .ps file is created.

Comment: Since this is a one-off, I suggest that you use a command shell and an executable to identify the process which has the file locked.  (search for a generic answer on identifying process). After you have done that and if you still have a problem that requires this kind of question, come back and ask how to implement the solution using WinAPI.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?894664-How-to-know-locked-file-process-VB6&p=5550225&viewfull=1#post5550225) is an WinAPI based solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @wqw for answer. I will try given solution.

Comment: Depending on the (content of the) file, it may not even be an issue with either Excel or your application, but some 3rd party software (AV or similar) having the file in access. A visual alternative to the below mentioned Openfiles command is [Lockhunter](https://lockhunter.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not keep a global database of who has what file open. This is for **speed** reasons. Although it does keep a list of other computers with files open on this computer.

For debugging purposes you can enable a global database. Remember to un-enable it.

So to enable

```
Openfiles /local on
```

then **reboot**.

To query

```
Openfiles /query /v
```

See

```
Openfiles /?

Openfiles /local /?

Openfiles /query /?
```